# Limit how long on steam

Tags: steam

My son, spends large amounts of time playing steam games. However, he uses his account for work as well.

How do I limit the amount that Steam.exe is allowed to run for?

Comment: This might get great non-tech answers on parenting SE

Comment: Isn't there like parental control on steam? Also what kind of work does your son do that needs steam?

Comment: I do not think his son does need Steam to work, but the computer which does run Steam. "Account" in this context does mean "Windows account"., not "Steam account".

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude games you do not want your son to play. You can restrict access to the store. But it seems there is no way to restrict the gaming time.

There is for sure external softwares that answer your needs. As I did not install and test any of them, I cannot say if they are safe or not. GameNanny seems to be one of them. Use it at your own risk and do a bit of googling before trying.

Otherwise, you can uninstall Steam when your son needs to work and reinstall it afterwards. If you disallow your son's account to install software, that should do the trick. It is a very annoying solution for you, even with a fast-installing Steam client.